# She'asa Nissim Lavoseinu | שעשה נסים לאבותינו - what did they say back then?

Tags: blessing, purim, megillat-esther

What was the second blessing mentioned by the Jews right after the miracle of Purim took place? If the second blessing on reading the Megillah mentions:

> "בימים **ההם** בזמן הזה"

"... in **those** days at this time", does this mean that the Jews said:

> "בימים **הזה** בזמן הזה"

"... in **these** days at this time", when they were rescued?

Comment: Notably, Purim is the *only* holiday for which this question can be asked, as Chanukah was not instituted at the time of the miracle (Shabbos 21b).

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that the _Halakhot_ of Purim, as they exist today, existed when the events themselves took place?